# What am I doing wrong here? if statements not adding up

Tags: java, if-statement

`total` in this case is 500. Trying to make a calculator, but not everything's adding up. It seems to skip the multiplication and just display **total*amount**. Is there something I'm doing wrong? EDIT: Discount: in the example, .92. I get 455000 if amount is 1000.

```
 if (wShipping==true){

  if (GroundShipping.isSelected()){
       if (amount<=99) {
          shipping=1.05;
          output.setText(output.getText() + amount + "\t" + total*1.05*amount*discount + "\n");
       }
       else{

     output.setText(output.getText() + amount + "\t" + total*amount*discount + "\n");
       }
  }
  if (AirShipping.isSelected()){
      shipping=1.1;
      output.setText(output.getText() + amount + "\t" + total*amount*1.1*discount + "\n");
  } 
  if (FedexShipping.isSelected()){
       shipping=1.25;
      output.setText(output.getText() + amount + "\t" + (total*amount*discount)*(1.25) + "\n");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Format the code please.

Comment: 1. you're missing a closing bracket. 2. what is the input (value of the parameters) and what would you expect it to print and what does it actually print ?

Comment: It depends on the value of amount, the value of discount, and what your output is - more information is needed.

Comment: Use String.valueOf() when using double or int values in String concat operation

Comment: In addition to the above comments about what kinds of input you're giving it and what kind of output you expect, you don't seem to be incorporating the variable `shipping` at all when you compute the output. Edit: that is to say, you're defining the variable, and then just multiplying by a constant amount equal to that variable instead. Why have the vbl at all then?

Comment: I think that you are missing a `}`, which closes the outermost if-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the following things--

1) Why is the variable shipping needed if you are directly using the value in the set statement

2) Use `else if` statement since all the options are exclusive

3) You might want to check the initial values for variables and the formula for calculating the price. Taking the initial values as given, the lowest possible price is-

```
Price = 1000*500*0.92 = 460000  (total x amount x discount)
```

Hence there must be something amiss with your initial values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe is the first rule of currency calculations:

[why not use double or float to represent currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)